# Dataframe Column Day Count which follow a hour column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column use to count each hour of a day, it look like this :

```
Index | Hour
______|______
     0|0
     1|1
     2|2
   ...|...
    22|22
    23|23
    24|0
```

I used the modulo operator to create the 'Hour' column

I want to create another column, for the day
It should look like this:

```
Index | Hour | Day
______|______|_____
     0|0     |0
     1|1     |0
     2|2     |0
   ...|...   |...
    22|22    |0
    23|23    |0
    24|0     |1
```

I tried to used modulo again, but i don't know if I should use it.
Any idea ?

Comment: try `df['Day'] = df['Hour'].eq(0).cumsum()-1` ?

Comment: What eq(0) mean ?

Comment: `eq` is equals , you can find docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)